# loop do only last value but it do all in debug mod

Tags: javascript, loops

My loop is supposed to downolad all the href of the page with the tagName a but it only download the last file of the loop.

```
$('#exportBilanProj').click( 
        function() { 
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 

            for(var count=0; count<links.length; count++) {
                var url = links[count].getAttribute('href');
                if(url && url.startsWith('rest/grm/export/bilan-projet/')) {
                    console.log( "value :" + url );
                    links[count].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));  
                }
            }

        });
```

but when I debug it all the information are taken and all file are downloaded

> value :rest/grm/export/bilan-projet/53035
>
> value :rest/grm/export/bilan-projet/53039
>
> value :rest/grm/export/bilan-projet/64001

I tried a break but nothing worked. Any idea ?

Comment: I assume that dispatchEvent works asynchronous and therefore takes the highest "count" value as it is defined in the execution scope and set to the highest value after the loop. Try replacing "var" with "let", let count = 0

Comment: the number depend it can be 3 (in this case) or 10/15 files.

Comment: most frequent problem of closure.

Comment: I didn't knew the existance of "let" and it's not recognized by ecplise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do not you use the "window.open"? I used this example and it looks like it worked correctly!

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 

            for(var count=0; count<links.length; count++) {
                var url = links[count].getAttribute('href');
                //remove for tests
                //if(url && url.startsWith('rest/groupama/export/bilan-projet/')) {
                    console.log( "value :" + url );
                    //window.open 
                    window.open(url);
                //}
            }
```

if the link you open is that of a download, it will just start downloading, if you use a compound url, you will have to adjust this before the "window.open (url)" example:

```
window.open(location.href + url);
```

or something like this...